# Problems Installing Mac OS X Snow Leopard build 10J3210 on a MacBook Air

Tags: mac

I'm trying to install this new build (10J3210) that apparently has TRIM support on the new mac book pro on my mac book air, but the installer doesn't go beyond the initial screen saying that the OS can't be installed on the MBA, is there any way of avoid or disabling this initial checking and let the installation go through?

Comment: Only Lion will have TRIM support. Are you sure you have Snow Leopard?

Comment: Apple has not qualified 10J3210 to work on the MacBook Airs, and probably never will. Getting around this installation check is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Spiff
I don't mind problems, if you know how to do it, please, let me know, thanks

Comment: @Randolph Potter

yes I have Snow Leopard as my MBA is a late 2010, and build 10J3210 as TRIM support on the new 2011 MBPs, I just get ahold of the install disks and I'm trying of do the install.

Answer (score 3):

10J3210 is a Sandy Bridge MBP-specific build.  It has no practical use for your MacBook Air, and was quite possibly not made with drivers that support your hardware. TRIM support for Toshiba controller-based SSD's may or may not be extractable(just guessing but there are probably kext's present in future builds of the OS), but its also possible you have an unsupported controller(since often SSD's in the same family have tweaks made to different volume sizes, meaning the 64GB may perform differently than the) 128.
I know that doesn't give you the exact assistance you're looking for, but it is all I know about the matter.  If you'd like me to dig up references I can, but my advice is to hold tight, support may be built-in by... this summer with Lion?

Comment: Thank you Scrilicious for your answer, really put me into context, I guess I'm going to wait for Lion this Summer, I have already tried the technical preview seeded for Apple and it does have TRIM support in my MBA (128 SSD), but I had to uninstall it because made the computer get so hot that the fan kick in a lot of times just running the OS alone, probably the final build will have better performance